# Not able to implement Saga ,

Tags: c#, wcf, nservicebus, esb

I have a Simple One Way messaging pattern , where i need to implement Saga , Because i need to call more then 5 web service , so any of the service dint respond i don't want the saga to be complete .

but when i am implementing saga , its Giving an error Could not found saga for message type and thus it invoke SagaNotFoundHandler

This is my Saga Data Model

```
 public class MySagaData : ContainSagaData
  {
    [Unique]
   public Guid OrderID { get; set; }

   public string SomeData { get; set; }
    }
```

This is Saga and message Handler Class

```
 public class PlaceOrderHandler : Saga<MySagaData> ,IHandleMessages<PlaceOrder>
{
    public override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga()
    {
        ConfigureMapping<PlaceOrder>(m => m.OrderID).ToSaga(s => s.OrderID);
    }

    public void Handle(PlaceOrder message)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ORder Recevied....for ID {0}", message.OrderID);
                //invoke 5 web service methods();
            MarkAsComplete();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
  }
```

This is my endpointConfig

```
   public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization,IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
              .DefaultBuilder()
              .UseTransport<Msmq>()
              .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
              .InMemorySagaPersister()
              .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
              .UnicastBus();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the process hosting the saga.");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your saga is never being created because you haven't implemented the IAmStartedByMessages interface.

Longer answer: based on your description, this doesn't look like a good use case for a saga.  If a message comes in, and the handler essentially just calls five web services in sequence via procedural code, all you really need is a vanilla message handler.  If one of the web services fails, you can throw an exception and the message will be retried via NSB multiple times.

All that said, it may be possible to use a saga to manage the web service call workflow.  Whether this makes sense or not for your case is something that you will have to determine.  It would look something like this (very rough, and assumes just 2 webservice calls):

- Your saga implements `IAmStartedByMessages<PlaceOrder>` and `IHandleMessages<WebService1Complete>`
- The process starts when a PlaceOrder message arrives.  The handler for PlaceOrder sets up your saga data and kicks off the Webservice Call #1.
- When WebService Call #1 completes, it publishes a WebService1Complete event
- The WebService1Complete handler then runs Webservice Call #2
- When Webservice Call #2 completes, it calls MarkAsComplete()